# compiler and endians

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, endianness

I have an ISA which is "kind" of little endian.
The basic memory unit is an integer and not byte.For example

```
00000000: BEFC03FF 00008000
```

Represents that the "low" integer is `BEFC03FF`  and "high" integer is `00008000`.
I need to read the value represented by  some bits.For example bits 31 till 47.
What I am doing in VS10 (c++) generate uint64_t var = 0x00008000BEFC03FF
after it use relevant mask and check the value of `var & mask`.
Is it legal to do that way?I do some assumption about uint64_t bits arrangement - is it legal?
Can I suppose that for very compiler and for every OS (without dependency on hw) the arrangement of bits in the uint64_t  will be this way?

Comment: What do you actually need to do?  Is there a need to read/write to specific memory addresses, or perform some other form of I/O?  If not, then you don't need to worry about endianness.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth - Didn`t I write what I want to do?If it is not I/O - why don`t I need to worry about endianness?I want to understand the concept and if it is compiler dependent

Comment: The result of stuff like `uint64_t var = 0x00008000BEFC03FF; var & mask` is not dependent on endianness.  Endianness only matters when you care about the underlying representation (which is why it's important for IO).

Comment: @OliCharlesworth -  But I present uint64_t var = 0x00008000BEFC03FF not uint64_t var = 0xBEFC03FF00008000.So I suppose something about uint64_t  representation.Whay can I do such assumption and what will happen if I switch to other compiler?

Comment: It doesn't matter.  The C++ language concerns itself with values, not the underlying mapping to hardware.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth - Is it a C++ standard that bits always for each compiler are arranged as in 0x00008000BEFC03FF?

Comment: It guarantees that, for example `var & 1` will always access the least-significant bit of the result.  But that has nothing to do with how it's arranged in memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right to be concerned, It *does* matter.

However, in this particular case, since ISA is little endian, i.e. if it has AD[31:0], the least significant bit of an integer is packed to bit 0.  Assuming your processor is also little endian, then nothing to worry about. when the data written to memory, it should have the right byte order

```
0000  FF
0001  03
0002  ..
```

suppose, if your external bus protocol is big endian and your processor is little endian. then a 16 bit integer in your processor, say 0x1234 would be `0001_0010_0011_0100` in native format, but `0010_1100_0100_1000` on the bus (assuming it's 16 bit).

In this case, multi byte data crosses endian boundary, the hardware will *only* swap *bits inside a byte*, because it must preserve the memory contiguousness between bytes. after hardware swap, it becomes:

```
0000 0001_0010
0001 0011_0100
```

then it is up to the software to swap the byte order